# how to catch checkbox value within "UL" tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul class = "classUL" id = "idUl1">
    <li>
        <label class = "classLabel">
            <input type = "checkbox" class = "classCheck" id = "idchk1"> Test Test Test
            </label>
    </li>
        <li>
        <label class = "classLabel">
            <input type = "checkbox" class = "classCheck" id = "idchk2" checked= "true" > Test Test Test
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class = "classUL" id = "idUl2">
    <li>
        <label class = "classLabel">
            <input type = "checkbox" class = "classCheck" id = "idchk1"> Test Test Test
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class = "classLabel">
            <input type = "checkbox" class = "classCheck" id = "idchk2" checked= "true" > Test Test Test
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have several lists... I want to get the value of the second checkbox, as I do in JS or jQuery? As I **walk** in the list for obtain the values of the checkbox (without id tag of checks)?

Comment: So how would you do it in jQuery?

Comment: sorry, i redid the question now!

Comment: You have duplicate `id`s, and therefore invalid HTML; any attempt at using JavaScript (particularly using `getElementById()`) is going to fail. Fix your HTML, and then we can maybe help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please have unique IDs in HTML Markup**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("ul.classUL").each(function(){

      $(this).find(".classCheck").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
      });

    });
});
```

Will give you the value of all checkboxes.

Comment: Or rather, without id tag of checks... tks!

Comment: I want  get the amount of 'checkbox' (LI) of 'idUl1'; scroll through the list by checking the 'checks'

Comment: i found it , but did not work! --> http://community.sitepoint.com/t/jquery-get-index-value-of-selected-li/5773

Comment: So you want to get the values of all checkbox inside `idUl1`?

Comment: First of all you have duplicate ID in HTML markup. Please make all the ID unique and update in the question then only i will be able to suggest you accordingly.

Comment: how to turn in jquery?
document.getElementById(ulID).getElementsByClassName("checks")[number].setAttribute("checked",false);

Comment: i'm happy, i did it!

var inputcheck = $("#"+ulID).find(".checks")[number];
$(inputcheck).attr("checked", false);

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:
`var v=document.getElementById("idchk2").value;`

Comment: So why did not not say that in your question @Fabio?